# I cant reference a class inside of paint(graphics g)

Tags: java, applet, null, awt, paint

Every time I try to reference the Drawer class I made within the pain method, it gives a null pointer exception. However, outside of the paint function the class works perfectly. The game class I made also works within the paint method. I am unsure of why I cannot reference the drawer class.

```
public class Main extends Applet implements Runnable, KeyListener {

public static boolean   CONSOLE = true;

// Integers
public final String     Title   = "";
public final int        res_X   = 800;
public final int        res_Y   = 600;

private Image           image;
private Graphics        second;
private URL             base;

public Game             game;
public Drawer           drawer;

public void init() {

    setSize(res_X, res_Y);
    setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    setFocusable(true);
    addKeyListener(this);
    Frame frame = (Frame) this.getParent().getParent();
    frame.setTitle(Title);

    try {
        base = getDocumentBase();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void start() {

    **Drawer drawer = new Drawer();**

    Thread mainThread = new Thread(this);
    mainThread.start();

    Thread gameThread = new Thread(game = new Game(drawer));
    gameThread.start();

}

public void run() {

    while (true)
        repaint();

}

public void paint(Graphics g) {

    **System.out.println((drawer == null)?"Null":"Exists");**
                            ^ if I replace with game it returns Exists

    g.fillRect(0, 0, res_X, 20);
    g.fillRect(0, res_Y - 20, res_X, 20);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 20, res_Y);
    g.fillRect(res_X - 20, 0, 20, res_Y);
    g.fillRect(game.player.xPos, game.player.yPos, 20, 60);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring it as local variable in the start method.

This:
    Drawer drawer = new Drawer();
Should just be:
    drawer = new Drawer();